# \documentclass[convert]{standalone} ignores linebreak

Tags: line-breaking, standalone, shell-escape

I tried to combine this answer [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible)
with my answer [Add column in a multicolumn table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82725/add-column-in-a-table/82734#82734)

But the `pdflatex -shell-escape table.tex` ignores linebreaks and the 3 tables are horizontally aligned and not vertically.

#### table.tex

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for nice lines
\usepackage{siunitx}  % nice numbers and units and 'S' in table
\usepackage{multirow} % enable \multirow command

\begin{document}
short answer to your question:\\
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|S|}
\hline
Genre & Name & {Weight}\\\hline
Humain & Aragorn & 102 \\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Hobbit}&Frodon & 32.1\\\cline{2-3}
    &Sam & 3.2 \\\cline{2-3}
    &Peregrin & 2.232\\\cline{2-3}
    &Meriadoc & 23 \\\hline
Elfe&Legolas & 34.5 \\\hline
\end{tabular}\\[1cm]


You can also use the power of booktabs and siunitx:\\
\begin{tabular}[ht]{l c S} % alignment l = left, c = centre, S = at decimal - needs siunitx
\toprule
Genre&Name& {Weight}\\  % protect non numbers with {} in S columns
\midrule
Elfe&Legolas & 34.5\\
Dwarf&Peter & 103.31\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\\[1cm]

And combine that with your table:\\
\begin{tabular}{c c S}
\toprule
Genre & Name & {Weight}\\\midrule
Humain & Aragorn & 102 \\\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Hobbit}&Frodon & 32.1\\\cline{2-3}
    &Sam & 3.2 \\\cline{2-3}
    &Peregrin & 2.232\\\cline{2-3}
    &Meriadoc & 23 \\\midrule
Elfe&Legolas & 34.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to pass the `varwidth` option to the class.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default the `standalone` class doesn't make paragraphs. However, with the `varwidth` option it does; so

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert]{standalone}
```

will do what you want, adjusting the width to the longest line.

Answer (score 11):

There are several possibilities:

### Table

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  line 1\\
  line 2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- A `tabular` adds `\strut`s in the rows, that might cause small white margins.
- Class `standalone` only uses the character bounding boxes and does not know about the bounding boxes of the glyph appearance. Thus additional margin makes sense to avoid cut off characters.
- The result can be run through `pdfcrop` to remove the remaining white margins.

### Package `varwidth`

The environment `varwidth` of the package with the same name is a kind of `minipage` that is horizontally shrunk afterwards:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
  line 1

  line 2
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Class `standalone` provides the option `varwidth` for this use case (thanks mozartstrasse for the hint). That simplifies the example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  line 1

  line 2
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Character clipping

The problem that the character glyphs are outside their official font bounding boxes cannot be solved inside TeX, because TeX does only knows the official character bounding boxes and not their visual appearances.

Example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \raggedleft
  \itshape
  line f

  line $\not$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Clipped result]

Part of `f` is not visible and `\not` has vanished entirely (extreme example, because `\not` has width zero, it overlaps the following relational operator).

As workaround a larger margin can be added:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
```

And the result is cropped, e.g. via `pdfcrop`:

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. That's very nice, but it only works for roman. If I use italics, a portion is clipped (as you see in the edit to the question). If I use a new font, a large chunk doesn't even appear. What is the general solution?

Comment: On second thought, let me ask it as a sequel since the issue appears to be orthogonal to standalone and varwidth.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[preview,multi]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\preview
line 1
\endpreview

\preview
line 2
\endpreview
\end{document}
```

Comment: That generates two pages. My understanding of the question was that the lines should be on one page in two lines and not in one line.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Your understanding is correct and mine is wrong. I did not read the question carefully. :-)